# Can't get image to show... PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Here is my code...
[image]

Here is my config file...

[image]

Here is my directory...

[image]

Here is how it looks...

[image]

EDITED:
.htaccess

```
Deny from all
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 

RewriteRule ^(images)(.*)/$ 404 [L] #deny images listing because we have allowed access to images below
RewriteRule ^(images)/(.*) $1/$2 [L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably because of permissions !

Comment: "<php echo base_url();?>/images/home.png" /> ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060571/image-unreadable-on-codeigniter-site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's your .htaccess. Add these.. and let me know if it works

```
RewriteRule ^(images)(.*)/$ 404 [L] #deny images listing because we have allowed access to images below
RewriteRule ^(images)/(.*) $1/$2 [L]
```

You need to allow images/assets to be accessed without rewriting. Your other rewrite rules slaps the URL on the index.php where you get a 404.

Edit: just noted the comments. Read up on this:

[image unreadable on codeigniter site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060571/image-unreadable-on-codeigniter-site)

And oh, you seem to have a missing "/" as well. :)

The following rewrites rules should be enough as well:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hmm Can you show source which falls on the browser? (Ctrl+U on firefox?). Also share your .htaccess file..

Comment: Hey Chinmay, I added the .htaccess file. I didn't understand what you we're getting at in the first part if you can reiterate it in a different way. Thanks so much for the help so far!

Comment: Remove the RewriteConds and move the two RewriteRules i shared above the one with index.php. Regd the base_url: `URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
| http://example.com/`

Comment: Aha! That did the trick!

The issue though is that if I take away this line...
        RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [L]

Then all of my pages don't work... Meaning I need to throw in index.php in the middle of everything...

For example if I take out the code...ReWrite Index rule
http://localhost:8888/baseline/verifylogin - will not work

I need to go back and change all the URL's to...
http://localhost:8888/baseline/index.php/verifylogin

And that is something I'm trying to avoid.

We're almost there! This is super helpful.

Comment: Yes- you need to place the index.php rule LAST, generally. Thinking about this, your RewriteConds DO allow access to the files and the directories. Have a look at the final URL being formed for the image. (VIew source code from the browser for the image .. google how to view if you don't know..)

Comment: If I take out all of the other commands in .htaccess the working file for the images is http://localhost:8888/baseline/images/home.png so it does work.

I just need to find out how to make sure I don't run into the problem of adding all the index.php's in the middle of my urls.

Answer (score 1):

You have missing the / in your path. Add one to the end of `$config['base_url']`, something like:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/baseline/';
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Hmm, rightclick on the image and try to copy the URL and see the error after accessing the image directly?

Comment: Here is the URL. Is this what you we're looking for?
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/baseline/images/home.png